# Pandas groupby nlargest sum

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I am trying to use `groupby`, `nlargest`, and `sum` functions in Pandas together, but having trouble making it work.

```
State    County    Population
Alabama  a         100
Alabama  b         50
Alabama  c         40
Alabama  d         5
Alabama  e         1
...
Wyoming  a.51      180
Wyoming  b.51      150
Wyoming  c.51      56
Wyoming  d.51      5
```

I want to use `groupby` to select by state, then get the top 2 counties by population. Then use only those top 2 county population numbers to get a sum for that state.

In the end, I'll have a list that will have the state and the population (of it's top 2 counties).

I can get the `groupby` and `nlargest` to work, but getting the sum of the `nlargest(2)` is a challenge.

The line I have right now is simply: `df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(2)`

Answer (score 47):

You can use `apply` after performing the `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('State')['Population'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).sum())
```

I think this issue you're having is that `df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(2)` will return a DataFrame, so you can no longer do group level operations.  In general, if you want to perform multiple operations in a group, you'll need to use `apply`/`agg`.

The resulting output:

```
State
Alabama    150
Wyoming    330
```

**EDIT**

A slightly cleaner approach, as suggested by @cs95:

```
df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0)
```

This is slightly slower than using `apply` on larger DataFrames though.

Using the following setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters

n = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), size=n),
                   'B': np.random.randint(10**7, size=n)})
```

I get the following timings:

```
In [3]: %timeit df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).sum())
103 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit df.groupby('A')['B'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0)
147 ms ± 3.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The slower performance is potentially caused by the `level` kwarg in `sum` performing a second `groupby` under the hood.

Comment: You should fix this by getting rid of the apply, using `df.groupby('State')['Population'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: your proposed solution of `.nlargest(2).sum(level=0)` is actually slower than using `apply` when the dataframe size is substantial.  The `level` kwarg in `sum` performs a second groupby operation under the hood, which I'm guessing is where the extra overhead comes from.

Comment: That's surprising. So one groupby + apply trumps two groupbys. Learned something new, cheers!

Comment: Will your solution work if `county`s were not unique? Imagine there are 2 rows like: `Alabama;e;2` and `Alabama;e;39` ? Would it `e` be considered instead of `c`?

Answer (score 7):

Using `agg`, the grouping logic looks like:

`df.groupby('State').agg({'Population': {lambda x: x.nlargest(2).sum() }})`

This results in another dataframe object; which you could query to find the most populous states, etc.

```
           Population
State
Alabama    150
Wyoming    330
```