# Pandas: How to sum the largest 3 values with respect to a sub-level in multilevel DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, sum

I have the data frame shown below. It is sorted so that 'POP' is in descending order with respect to each 'STATE'. Now I want to sum the largest three values of 'POP' with respect to each 'STATE', how should I do this?

```py
import pandas as pd
d = [['X','q',123383],['X','w',43857349],['X','e',236657],['X','r',23574594],
        ['Y','t',547853],['Y','y',46282134],['Y','u',43857439],['Y','i',32654893],['Y','i',95678312]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['STATE','COUNTY','POP'])
df.sort_values(['STATE','POP'], ascending=[True, False]).set_index(['STATE','COUNTY'])

print(sorted_df)

# sorted_df:
                   POP
STATE COUNTY          
X     w       43857349
      r       23574594
      e         236657
      q         123383
Y     i       95678312
      y       46282134
      u       43857439
      i       32654893
      t         547853
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby nlargest sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390634/pandas-groupby-nlargest-sum)

Answer (score 3):

There's `nlargest` that does not require pre-sort:

```
df.groupby(['STATE']).POP.nlargest(3)
```

gives you

```
STATE   
X      1    43857349
       3    23574594
       2      236657
Y      8    95678312
       5    46282134
       6    43857439
Name: POP, dtype: int64
```

and if you only care for the sum:

```
df.groupby(['STATE']).POP.nlargest(3).sum(level=0)
```

gives:

```
STATE
X     67668600
Y    185817885
Name: POP, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to reassign after you sort the dataframe (perhaps you meant to call the result `sorted_df`).

Group by the state level (or `level=0` given that it is a multi-index of State and County), then apply a lambda taking the head for the top three (given that the data was sorted in descending order by population for each state) and sum the result.

```
top_n = 3
df = df.sort_values(['STATE','POP'], ascending=[True, False]).set_index(['STATE','COUNTY'])
>>> df.groupby(level='STATE').apply(lambda x: x.head(top_n).sum())
             POP
STATE           
X       67668600  # w: 43857349 + r: 23574594 + e: 236657
Y      185817885  # i: 95678312 + y: 46282134 + u: 43857439
```